# Outputting nodes from a LinkedList

Tags: c#

I am currently learning data structure using c#, the topic linked list. I created the Node and LinkedList classes

```
namespace DSA___Linked_List.Models
{
    public  class Node
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
        public Node? Next { get; set; }

        public void DisplayNode()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Data);
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace DSA___Linked_List.Models
{
    public class LinkedList
    {
        public Node Head { get; set; }

        public void DisplayList()
        {
            Node current = Head;

            while (current != null)
            {
                current.DisplayNode();
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in main program.cs

```
Node nodeA = new Node();
nodeA.Data = 253;

Node nodeB = new Node();
nodeB.Data = 456;

Node nodeC = new Node();
nodeC.Data = 345;

Node nodeD = new Node();
nodeD.Data = 123;

LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.Head = nodeA;

linkedList.DisplayList();

nodeA.Next = nodeB;
nodeB.Next = nodeC;
nodeC.Next = nodeD;

linkedList.DisplayList();
```

How would the first and second outputs be different?

```
253
253 456 345 123
```

I thought the output would be the same, as I made the change of objects nodeA, nodeB, and nodeC but not the linkedList.

Comment: You are only linking nodes at the `Next = nodeB`-step. Before this there is no ling between NodeA and nodeB, so naturally the linked list only contains NodeA

Comment: I'm confused about why the second output displays the values of all nodes from a to d.

Comment: The code follows the `Next` links that it has explicitly set through the list.